# How to apply map and if condition won useselector state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Iam facing some issue on my react app.  I want to show multiple user by using map but he gave me error . My data is come from redux reducer
And I want to show that data  on my web when data.lenght greater then 0 or not equal to 0 but nothing happen. Code are attached guide me if you know [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBci.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You should mention which error you get and post some code instead of a photo

Comment: Bro I got data.map is not a function error  when iterate after apply map on useselector state   .

Comment: And sorry my code is now vanish form my vs code

Answer (score 0):

Because map normaly returns a new array and in your code you only execute function that returns nothing.

So you can replace curly braces with normal after the arrow

```
data.map(user => (
    <Card key={user.userId}>
     ...and rest of your code
))
```

or add return to function

```
data.map(user => {
  return (    
      <Card key={user.userId}>
     ...and rest of your code
    )
});
```